# Sort entry titles alphabetically excluding 'The'?

Tags: entries, forloop, ordering, sorting, order

I need to list the names of all of my entries in alphabetical order excluding 'the' (which could only be at the beginning). I've looked around online, but I was only able to find a code segment (which I've modified to fit my needs). However, it's still incorrectly sorting them as you can see in the attached image.

Current code:

```
{% for entry in craft.entries.section('partners').featuredMediaPartner('1').order('(CASE WHEN title LIKE "The %" THEN SUBSTRING(title, 3) ELSE title END ) asc') %}
```

Please help me fix this issue, thanks.

[image: Entries not being correctly sorted]

Answer (score 3):

According to [SUBSTRING](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_substr), the first character starts at 1.  So if you wanted to start at the position immediate after `The` (with one space), you'd need to start at position 5.

Just did a test locally and it works as expected for me if I use:

```
.order('(CASE WHEN title LIKE "The %" THEN SUBSTRING(title, 5) ELSE title END ) asc')
```